# To Query the DB from the DB Class or From the Data Model Class in MVC?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, class, model-view-controller

I have a situation where I use a Data Model Class called 'Stock' to organize the output of my DB. Stock takes quote information from an SQLite DB and sets it's local fields to be said values. Using getters I obtain the values from a Stock.

I use a DB Class I created by extending SQLiteOpenHelper and currently I have all DB logic in this as public methods. However, I feel this may not be the best/most logic way of doing this.

I'm a purist, because I feel these best practices lead to the most readable code, so I was wondering if it's standard to contain all DB logic in each respective Data Model Class, or if putting it centrally in the DB Class is also accepted.

I would very much appreciate your opinions and any examples on this subject. I'm trying to implement a paradigm which I believe is MVC, or close to, and I'm not sure how this aspect fits...

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to separate the Data Model from the Database Implementation. As you said, it's more readable.

Remember that in Object Oriented Programming, each outside-world object is modeled by a class. Each object should encapsulate all it's functionality within the class, and expose some connections to the outside world in the form of methods and functions.

That being said, objects interact by calling each others methods, but **how** these methods work internally is hidden. Each object is a **black box** to other objects.

Now back to your example, your **Stock model** is responsible for creating, generating, computing... data. Your Stock object should use another object (the database object) as a black box to save this information. Why is this so important??? Because tomorrow you may want to switch your storage method, maybe you'll store it in a plain text file, or maybe online. If you separate logic and storage, you could just change the implementation of the storage class, leaving the functions prototypes almost identical (with some minor differences) but you wouldn't need to modify your Stock class.

But this is not the rule, and each project is different. As developers, we're responsible for understanding the pros and the cons of each approach and make our best bet.

Comment: You speak in ways I can understand and appreciate. I didn't realize why this separation was so important. This made it click, thank you so much. If I encapsulate everything in the Model, I never need to guess where it is, and as you say, I can throw out the DB layer, and replace it with some other layer if need be. EUREKA! You're awesome.

Comment: @AutoM8R Thanks for the compliments! :)